# fixed div but inside a specific container

Tags: html, css, fixed

I want a sidebar to exclude from any scroling behaviour on page - so it is `position:fixed`.

But I want it to be inside `wrap` as a parent container and `right:0` from `wrap` and not from window.

How to do this ?

```css
.wrap{width:250px; margin:0 auto; height:100vh;background:silver;}
.sidebar{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;height:100vh;background:gold;}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='sidebar'>sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: position:sticky instead ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, sticky... I'm not sure, pls example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is to not define `right` and tell the browser to use the *static* position. For this you need to make sure the static position is on the right.

Here is an example where you have to adjust the direction (and reset it for the content)

```css
.wrap {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150vh;
  background: silver;
  direction:rtl;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: gold;
}

.wrap > div:last-child {
  direction:ltr;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='sidebar'>sidebar</div>
  <div> some content</div>
</div>
```

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width):

> For the purposes of this section and the next, the term "static position" (of an element) refers, roughly, to the position an element would have had in the normal flow.

Then

> If all three of 'left', 'width', and 'right' are 'auto': First set any 'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0. Then, if the 'direction' property of the element establishing the static-position containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the static position and apply rule number three below; otherwise, set 'right' to the static position and apply rule number one below.

---

Here is another idea with `position:sticky`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150vh;
  background: silver;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  float:right; /* Yes float!*/
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: gold;
}


body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='sidebar'>sidebar</div>
  <div> some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever use of `dir`

Comment: I really must say - why  `position:fixed-in-parent` - for example - does not exist ?

Comment: @qadenza it does and it's called `sticky` but it would be trick in this case .. will add in the answer too